# host only network xen 4.4

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, xen

I have one IP address (ipv4) and I am trying to install a domU (debian stable) on a dom0 which runs the latest xen 4.4.1 on debian testing.

I have created xenbr0 bridge and it is mapped to my eth0.

My domU can be started using `xl create my.cfg` and the installer (using the debian installer with initrd.gz and vmlinuz) starts. Then auto network config tries to obtain an ip via dhcp in my domU but the networking fails cause I do not have a dhcp server.

How can I manually set my domU to connect to the outside (wild internet) via the xenbr0 so that I can do a network install?

Thanks for any pointers.

**update: .cfg**

Nothing special there really

```
kernel = "/tmp/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/tmp/initrd.gz"
extra = "debian-installer/exit/always_halt=true -- console=hvc0"
vcpus = 4
memory = 2048
name = "debianvm"
vif = ['bridge=xenbr0']
disk = ['phy:/dev/vg0/debianvm,xvda,w']
```

Comment: Please post your my.cfg.

Comment: Added my.cfg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup NAT for your VM manually for example like this:

1. Create another bridge: `brctl addbr xenbr1`
2. Add it to your VM: `bridge=xenbr1`
3. Bring the bridge UP with some network, for example `ifconfig xenbr1 192.168.0.1/24 up`
4. Setup a DHCP server and configuration for your network

   `subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     range 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.50;
     option routers 192.168.0.1;
     default-lease-time 600;
     max-lease-time 7200;
   }`

   And bind DHCP to your bridge xenbr1. 
   But **you can skip** this step. You'll just need to specify a static IP inside your installer.
5. Add a SNAT rule, for example: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source ...`
6. Allow forwarding `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1`

After that you'll have a working network in your VM.
Also you can specify `vif = ['bridge=xenbr1,script=vif-nat']` in your VM config (more info here http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking). It will automate some NAT settings. But in older versions of Xen it behaved strangely. I personally like to control anything so i prefer the method i described earlier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Glueon I'll try that tomorrow and let you know how things went!

Comment: btw from the wiki page: The XL toolstack will never modify the network configuration and expects that the administrator will have configured the host networking appropriately. That is where I was stuck ;-)

Comment: Where would I setup 4. if I wanted to do that out of curiosity?

Comment: Just install `isc-dhcp-server` in your dom0. Modify `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` setting `INTERFACES=xenbr1` then add the block i gave earlier at the end of `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`.

Comment: 6. should be this, right ->  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1  at least that is what my sysctl.conf recommends

Comment: 5. the SNAT rule what should I use for the --to-source? etho or xenbr0?

Comment: 6 - yes, this works.
5 - In --to-source you should put the IP address used for outgoing connections. So that most likely is one on the eth0

Comment: ok I think I have everything setup besides the dhcp, iptables man pages did not provide me with a `--to-source` option but just with `--to` so I used the later ... I just started my vm and tried a static ip but no luck yet ...

Comment: iptables for POSTROUTING nat looks like this:

`Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere  to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: What does tcpdump -nli xenbr0 shows? Does any traffic come from bridge?

Comment: The xenbr0 bridge got traffic.Do I need to reboot dom0, probably no, right?

Comment: for the debian net installation for a domU do I need a valid nameserver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17730/discussion-between-glueon-and-mahatmanich).